# Dual monitor error on single monitor setup

Tags: 12.04, video, multiple-monitors, dualhead

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 x86. Once I had two monitors and used the Nvidia control panel to configure dual screen to get a single desktop stretched across the two monitors.

[image]

Then I had one monitor removed and now every time  I login I get the following error mesage:

[image]
How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find the cause, but I solved the issue by setting the "Launcher placement" to "laptop" under "display settings".